# Static library test using XCTestCase

Tags: ios, ios7, static-libraries, xctest, mainbundle

I am creating object of ISession class which gives me singleton instance,

when object is allocated and initialized it pickup values from plist file,

I am getting nil on `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Manifest" ofType:@"plist"]` so that object creation get fail.

Can someone provide solution, So that I can write test cases within static library instead of project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Mock objects in code, representing your data from the plist and instantiate them in the setUp method of your Test file

Static Libraries are not meant to have resources.